# Last chosen selection goes to top of spinner options

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I am working on an app and I am using spinners.

However, there are a lot of options for the user to choose(18).

Does anyone know if it is possible to code a spinner so that the last selection the user selected will go to the top of the spinner options? This way he/she will not need to scroll through the list again...

Thanks!

Adapters:

```
 final ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter5 = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this,
            R.layout.spinner_layout, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Hours));
    myAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_layout);
    spinnerDowntimeHours.setAdapter(myAdapter5);

    spinnerDowntimeHours.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position2, long l) {


            switch (position2) {
                case 0:
                    break;
                case 1:
                    break;
                case 2:
                    break;
                case 3:
                    break;
                case 4:
                    break;
                case 5:
                    break;
                case 6:
                    break;
                default:
                    break;

            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            String[] list = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Hours);

            spinnerDowntimeHours.setSelection(Integer.parseInt(list[0]));
        }

    });
```

Comment: Do you want the selected item to actually move to the top of the list? or just to be shown on top when the user opens up a spinner with a selection?

Comment: Both sound okay.. it is just for convenience so that they do not have to scroll each time to find their name

Comment: Are you using custom adapter for your spinners?

Comment: I think so not sure... I will add the code I  use for adapters above

Comment: @elmorabea ....

Comment: I have created a sample, the drop down auto scrolls to show the selected item, could the problem be that it is not highlighted?

Comment: Apply background with different color for android:state_activated to better show user which item is selected

Comment: would It be possible for you to show me the sample?? @elmorabea

Answer (score 0):

Here's the sample I tried with, setting spinner adapter

```
String[] stringArray = new String[20];
for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
    stringArray[i] = "Item " + i;
}

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, stringArray);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);
Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

spinner_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_select"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"/>
```

bg_select.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/colorAccent" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/colorAccent"/>
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@color/colorAccent"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary"/>
</selector>
```